# angular state.go function does not redirect to previous page

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I have to display a modal from the main menu.  The modal displays correctly.  But when I close the modal, i want the previous url to be displayed.
This is the code for the modal:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
      .state('pos',{
        url: '/pos',
        templateUrl: 'views/pos.html',
        controller: 'PosCtrl'
      })
      .state('vAnalyze',{
        url: '/vAnalyze',
        templateUrl: 'views/vAnalyze.html',
        controller: 'VAnalyzeCtrl'
      })
       .state('reportSetting',{
        url: '/reportSettingModal',
        onEnter: function($modal){
          $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'views/reportSettingModal.html',
               controller: 'ReportSettingModalCtrl'
          });
        }
      })
      .state('error', {
        url: '/error',
        templateUrl: 'lib/views/error.html',
        controller: 'ErrorCtrl'
      });

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
  })

  .run(['AuthService', 'configSettings', '$rootScope', function (AuthService, configSettings, $rootScope) 
  { // Apply Product Code 
    configSettings.productCode = 'VANALYZE';
    AuthService.configProduct(configSettings.productCode); 
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
        $rootScope.$previousState = from;
    });
   } ]);
```

This is the function to close the modal:

```
 $scope.close = function() {
      $uibModalInstance.close();
      $state.go($rootScope.$previousState.name, {
        url: $rootScope.$previousState.url,
        templateUrl: $rootScope.$previousState.templateUrl,
        controller: $rootScope.$previousState.controller
      });
    };
```

When I step into the code the url, templateUrl and controller all have the correct data.  But the page is not displayed.
The page displayed when I close the modal is `reportSettingModal`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the URL change, or even that doesn't happen?
BTW - why are you passing to $state.go second parameter this object.
Also, I never use router for modals, but it depends on the UC (e.g. the modal should be bookmark-able)

Comment: The url does change when I initiate the modal from different pages.  For the state.go function, I tried just doing this: `$state.go($rootScope.$previousState.name)`  But the page was not changing.  SO I thought if it was more explicit it would work.  But it did not.  I don't know what you mean by 'use a router for modals'.  Typically, I have called modals from a page and when it closes the main page is visible.  This modal is called from the main menu.

Comment: Just do the modal-open from the ng-click of the menu bar. You don't need the router for that

Answer (score 0):

You can go by using `$state.go` but that is not a good practise. Because, in general, there should not be any relation between displaying a modal and state change. Showing a modal should be independent of route configuration. Just use something like `addClass` or `removeClass` to show the modal when you click on link or button.

```
$scope.show = function (){
// open modal here by adding a class to the modal element
}
```

In the same way close the modal.

Comment: WHere do I put this show function?  IT is in the menu bar that when a user clicks an icon the modal shows.

Comment: Then write it in `mainController`, if it is visible and clickable from all states and if you want to write this `mainController` should be either the parent controller of all controllers or independent means have `menuController`.

Comment: I decided to go into a different direction.  I removed the open.modal from the .state function because it is not really a state. (sorry, I am learning angular and didn't realize this).  I added a click event to the header template and added an open modal function to all of the pages.  It is now working as aspected.